# Cuboid UV map edges doesn't match

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to unwrap a cuboid to apply a texture. I defined the seams, unwraped the object. But when I look in the UV editing window, I have edges which are supposed to be the same on the 3D model (and it's the case since when I select one, the other automatically gets selected) but have different sizes. I can't change one without changing the other because they are linked.
My three scales are set to 1, so I'm a bit confused.

How could I fix this issue?

Here are the UV map

[image: UVmap with thexture]

and the cuboid

[image: 3D cuboid model]

Thank you

Comment: In the UV editor enable "constrain to image bounds". then do select all (press A), then scale on Y only (press S+Y) and rescale.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm ! Any idea why I had such a scale in the first place ?

Comment: I don't know how you unwrapped. Check also that you apply scale in object mode before unwrapping, to avoid distortions